# gitlab CI on MR

Tags: continuous-integration, yaml, gitlab, gitlab-ci, repo

I've forked a project repo from master and created my own tests (`.mygitlab_ci.yaml`) that are supposed to extend those of the master repo and run on a locally dedicated machine that replicates the env of the master repo runner machine.

I expected a MR towards master to trigger the CI of master, on the master elected runner, but the CI appears to keep running *my* tests, not master's.

Is there a way to control this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid there is no way to achieve it.

The only way I found was to push a side branch upstream to the master repo and issue the merge request from the side branch **within** master repo.